# php null byte injection?

Tags: php, null, byte

```
$num = $_GET['fileid'];                        // get file id

$realfile = "filename".$num.'.txt';
```

My question is that is it still possible to null poison this? .'.txt' at the end does not disappear with null byte injection according to my experimentation. Is there a way to null byte this?

Comment: In Ext3/4 FS `\0` characters are just stripped

Comment: I would remove all doubts and simply validate the input; using a whitelist, using a regex, casting to int or whatever applies best.

Comment: %00 --- http://ha.ckers.org/blog/20060914/php-vulnerable-to-null-byte-injection/

Comment: @jeroen Yep, sanitizing would prevent it always.

Comment: @Userpassword, even with %00 the '.txt' part would not dissappear right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe your code might be susceptible to directory traversal attacks - if someone provided "/../../foo" as a `fileid`, then the path would be `"filename/../../foo.txt"`, which could be a valid target. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_traversal

I'm with @jeroen and @shiplu.mokadd.im who suggests sanitizing your input - assuming `fileid` is a number then the `intval()` function will do you fine:

```
$num = $_GET['fileid'];
$num = intval( $num );
if( $num == 0 ) {
    echo "Invalid file ID: Not a number.";
    exit;
} else {
    $fileName = 'filename' . $num . '.txt'; 
    if( !file_exists( $fileName ) ) {
        echo "Invalid file ID: Doesn't exist.";
    } else {
        // do something
    }
}
```